# How to translate the search plugin from impresspages 4.0?

Tags: impresspages

Is there a way to translate the search plugin from impresspages version4.0? 
The form label and form button are still in EN, in my case is need DE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. "Translate all" plugin should do this for you.